# Android homescreen Widget - Search

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-softkeyboard

I was wondering if it was possible to create a Android HomeScreen widget which has a search bar, which when a user enters some text and presses enter, it will open the corresponding app and searches within in.

I currently have a widget that contains a logo and a text view, however, when you click on the widget, nothing happens. The keyboard doesnt even pop up. Can anyone help?

Currently I have it randomly setting the textview with a random number, and onclick, changing the number

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_menu" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_search_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/FontStyle.edit_text_view_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="android.widget.SearchWidget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/search_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
```

Class:

```
public class SearchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

      // Get all ids
      ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
              SearchWidget.class);
      int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
      for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        // create some random data
        int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.search_widget_layout);
        // Set the text
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_search_textview, String.valueOf(number));

        // Register an onClickListener
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SearchWidget.class);

        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_search_textview, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
      }
    }

}//End of Search Widget Class
```

App Provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/search_widget_layout"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `TextView` does not accept user input. A `TextView` is a label, for output.

In an activity, you can use an `EditText` for user input. `EditText` is not supported in an app widget.

Hence, to your question:

> I was wondering if it was possible to create a Android HomeScreen widget which has a search bar, which when a user enters some text and presses enter, it will open the corresponding app and searches within in.

That is not strictly possible.

Comment: So you are unable to create a search widget?

Comment: @JamesKing: If by "search widget" you mean a widget that accepts text input used for a search, correct. There is nothing stopping you from responding to a tap on a widget and offering a search interface at that point via an activity. AFAIK, the Google Search widget worked that way: tapping on the "field" would bring up a dialog-themed activity that overlaid the app widget, with a real `EditText` for typing.